# StoryBoard image from referenced folder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have been trying to get images in my referenced folder(blue folder) in Storyboard. But I haven't had any luck. I tried putting something like this in the image field "images/image.png" but apparently it doesn't work.

Anybody ever encountered the same problem?

Comment: Did you add the images to the correct target ?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure I have added them to the correct target

Comment: Do the images appear in the media library tab in IB?

Comment: Yeah the IB can find them. I also tried deleting the app and clean(the normal procedures).

Comment: So... what is the problem exactly? If you drag an image from the library it would be added as an `UIImageView` in your storyboard. As for the `image` field (I assume you're talking about setting an image to a control like a `UIButton`) you just put the image name ("image.png" for example) it even autocompletes this for you...

Comment: Even though Storyboard can autocomplete it with the correct image, the image dont show up in the simulator or the device. Maybe I'm confused about your media library tab. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Oh i made it work, I just accidentally removed the images from my external folder. It works by putting the "<folder name>/<imagename>.png". Although this creates another problem in the Storyboard which is it will show "?" for the UIElement. But the images are found when I run it on simulator/device.

Comment: Yes this happens because now what is added to the target is the referenced folder instead of the actual image files (you can verify this in the Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources). I guess a workaround would be to create a normal group and add the images as references to this group (instead of the containing folder), that way both IB and the simulator/device would reference the image just using `imagename.png`.